# Select prices/sizes from tables using joiner table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery

I am trying to create a product page that shows the product info, as well as prices and sizes. Each product will have multiple prices and sizes.

I have multiple tables (products, sizes, prices) and I am using a "joiner" table that only has those tables as foreign keys. This is where I am getting the most confused.

SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  description TEXT,
);

CREATE TABLE sizes (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  height INT,
  width INT,
  garmentSize TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE prices (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  price INT
);  

CREATE TABLE product_price_size (           --joiner table
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  productId INTEGER REFERENCES products(id),
  priceId INTEGER REFERENCES prices(id),
  sizeId INTEGER REFERENCES sizes(id)
);


INSERT INTO products (name, description)
VALUES ('Take A Hike', 'Take A Hike vinyl decal');
INSERT INTO products (name, description)
VALUES ('Wanderlust', 'Wanderlust vinyl decal');

INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO prices (price) VALUES (8);

INSERT INTO sizes (height, width, garmentSize) VALUES (3, 3, null);
INSERT INTO sizes (height, width, garmentSize) VALUES (4, 5, null);
INSERT INTO sizes (height, width, garmentSize) VALUES (7, 2, null);

INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (1, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (2, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO product_price_size (productId, priceId, sizeid) VALUES (2, 1, 3);
```

I need to get each product to show multiple sizes that has a price associated with it, and I am not sure how get that done. I am using Angular to get to `"mysite.com/products/2"` which in this example is getting the 2nd product from the products table, so if I currently go to the products page, an error will occur because there are currently three "product.id"s that reference product id 2.

QUERY

```
SELECT products.name, prices.price, sizes.height, sizes.width FROM products
INNER JOIN product_price_size ON products.id = product_price_size.productId
INNER JOIN prices ON prices.id = product_price_size.priceId
INNER JOIN sizes  ON sizes.id  = product_price_size.sizeId
```

I think I might need a subquery, but I'll admit I am lost on this.

[Please see SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b7410/1)

I hope this isn't too confusing, and any thoughts or even better ideas for the way I'm doing it are very appreciated. Thanks!!
Keith

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.  Your query (superficially) looks fine for what you want to do.

Comment: To build a product page you probably want 2 queries, one for the product title and the second for a price/size table on the page.

Comment: @Serg I was thinking I could do it in one query, but I ended up using your idea and just making two queries, which worked. I appreciate the input!